# How to use function by having its name as a string

Tags: string, matlab, function, eval, sequence

Suppose you want to use a sequence of functions defined in MATLAB, and you just have the name of those functions as string variables. Let say you have already created `fun1`, `fun2`, ...,`funN`, and you also have a vector of strings as `['fun1','fun2',...,'funN']`. How to call each function automatically without being forced to write name of each function one by one?

Comment: You can use `feval` to call a function, but why do you have the function names in strings? It may be worth telling us what you're trying to accomplish so we can help you come up with a better option. typically you'd want to just store an array of function handles or something

Comment: I have nearly fifty functions, and I need to run a code and do some computation by each one of them, mostly about differential equations and ode45 function. I do not want to change my code every time I change the function. I generated a string so that I write the root code in a more general way and I will set `N=...` at the beginning every time.

Comment: Right but why do you have 50 functions with names like `fun1`, `fun2` etc? Maybe you should have one function that you have some additional inputs to modify how it behaves rather than keeping track of 50 functions.

Comment: These functions has already been generated. In addition, each one of them has a long expression. Combining them will decrease the speed and accuracy of computations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `str2func`. Of course, if the functions have been defined as function handles (e.g. `fun1 = @(x)x+x.^2+sqrt(x))`), you can skip the str2func step below.

```
strList= {'sum','mean','max','min'};
funList = cellfun(@str2func,strList,'uniformOutput',false);

nFunctions = length(funList);
data = rand(10,1);
results = zeros(nFunctions,1)

for iFunction = 1:nFunctions
    results(iFunction) = fulList{iFunction}(data);
end
```

Comment: Seems to me function handles would be the way to go.